Im trying to change the style of text using buttons but cant get it to work for multiple with the same id
Im trying to make a button that can add and remove a style for certain parts of my website in this case changing the background colors of the elements.
Although the buttons work fine when their is one element when I have two for eg.thing One and thing three the button only effects the first one and not all of the  with the same id.
I hope I explained that ok I'm very new to coding and this is my first website so please be kind hahahhaha


var blue = document.getElementById('blue');
function changeBlue() {
  for(var i = 0; i < blue.classList.length; i++) {
    if(blue.classList[i].indexOf('body') >= 0) {
      blue.classList.remove('body');
      blue.classList.add('blue');
    } else { 
      blue.classList.remove('blue');
      blue.classList.add('body'); 
    }
  }
}


var pink = document.getElementById('pink');
function changePink() {
  for(var i = 0; i < pink.classList.length; i++) {
    if(pink.classList[i].indexOf('body') >= 0) {
      pink.classList.remove('body');
      pink.classList.add('pink');
    } else { 
      pink.classList.remove('pink');
      pink.classList.add('body'); 
    }
  }
}
 
.blue { font-family: Helvetica;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color:#003eff;
     } 
  
.pink { font-family: Helvetica;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color:#eb00ff;
     }

.body { font-family: Helvetica;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #000000;
        background-color:#ffffff;
     }
 
<button class="body" onclick="changeBlue()">Make Blue</button>
<button class="body" onclick="changePink()">Make Pink</button>

<span class="body" id="blue">thing One</span>
<span class="body" id="pink">thing Two</span>
<span class="body" id="blue">thing three</span>




You can not have multiple same id used. Id must be unique. It is invalid HTML. You can use same class for example (and then you can loop through same class element with forEach)

The issue with the above code is that you have the same id for multiple elements. This is not valid in JavaScript, and it will always only execute your code for the first element id.
You can read more on the use of getElementById here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById
I have converted blue into a class rather than id for elements thing One and thing three. An additional class selected will now be used to add and remove the desired colour. See below:
HTML:
<button class="make_blue" onclick="changeBlue()">Make Blue</button>
<button class="make_pink" onclick="changePink()">Make Pink</button>

<span class="body blue">thing One</span>
<span class="body" id="pink">thing Two</span>
<span class="body blue">thing three</span>

CSS:
    .blue.selected {
        font-family: Helvetica;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: #003eff;
    }

    .pink {
        font-family: Helvetica;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: #eb00ff;
    }

    .body {
        font-family: Helvetica;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #000000;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }

JS:
    function changeBlue() {
        var blueElements = document.getElementsByClassName('blue');
        for (var i = 0; i < blueElements.length; i++) {
            if (blueElements[i].classList.contains('selected')) {
                blueElements[i].classList.remove('selected');
            } else {
                blueElements[i].classList.add('selected');
            }
        }
    }

    function changePink() {
        var pinkElement = document.getElementById('pink');
        if (pinkElement.classList.contains('pink')) {
            pinkElement.classList.remove('pink');
            pinkElement.classList.add('body');
        } else {
            pinkElement.classList.remove('body');
            pinkElement.classList.add('pink');
        }
    }

